# Salesforce data move utility (SFDMU) plugin

Tags: apex

I found in the forcedotcom github repo this plugin: [SFDMU](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SFDX-Data-Move-Utility); i've read the documentation, but i didn't understand how it works for sObjects relationships.
Can someone with more experience with this plugin tell me how to configure export.json in order to export, for example, Accounts with theri childs (contacts) and how to configure export.json also for inserting them into the org via this plugin.

I've tried a couple of simple exports and imports but i can't grasp how to do this mantaining sObjects relationships

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: The documentation is not really detailed but you can find the example at this link. Please note the external ID parameter in json which maintains the relationship. https://help.sfdmu.com/plugin-basics/basic-usage/minimal-configuration

Comment: @manjit5190 i followed your advice, but i set externalId as an empty string

Comment: externalId needs to reference a field on the object that is unique

Comment: @cropredy i set it as an empty string and it worked for me; it mantained relationships